# File not found error python

Tags: python

```
import os
import time
torrent_folder = os.listdir(r'C:\users\chris\desktop\torrents')
for files in torrent_folder:
    if files.endswith(".torrent"):
        print(files + time.ctime(os.path.getatime(files)))
```

I am getting a file not found error when running this script.
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'TORRENT NAME.torrent`'

everything works fine until `time.ctime(os.path.getatime(files)` 
is added into the mix.

I would like the script to display 'torrent name' 'date last modified'
for each file in the folder.

Why is the error referencing a file, by name that it says it is unable to find and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `files` variable is the file name *only,* not the complete path. Hence it will be looking for it in your *current working directory,* not where `listdir` found it.

The following code will use the *full* path name:

```
import os
import time
folder = r'C:\users\chris\desktop\torrent'
files = os.listdir(folder)
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".torrent"):
        print(file + " " + time.ctime(os.path.getatime(os.path.join(folder,file))))
```

The `os.path.join()` combines `folder` and `file` to give you a *full* path specification. For example, `os.path.join("/temp","junk.txt")` would give you `/temp/junk.txt` (under UNIX).

Then it uses that in exactly the same way you tried to use just the `file` variable, getting the last access time and formatting it in a readable manner.

Comment: I'm fairly new to python, could you explain exactly how this magic works `time.ctime(os.path.getatime(os.path.join(folder,file)))`

Comment: @Cs142, I'll add more meat to the answer rather than answer in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

It require absolute [path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getatime).

> os.path.getatime(path)
>
> *Return the time of last access of path.*

so, `open('xxx.torrent')` will not work.

Instead, use `open('C:\users\chris\desktop\torrents\xxx.torrent')`

```
import os
import time
torrent_folder = os.listdir(r'C:\users\chris\desktop\torrents')
for files in torrent_folder:
    if files.endswith(".torrent"):
        filepath = os.path.join('C:\users\chris\desktop\torrents',files)
        print(files + time.ctime(os.path.getatime(filepath)))
```

Comment: Aaron, `torrent_folder` is a list, you probably want to use the original _path_ in your `os.path.join()` call.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for correcting. I have modified my answer.