# Python - Can't locate downloaded file to unzip

Tags: python, selenium, unzip

Using selenium, I was able to automate the download of a zip file and save it to a specified directory. When I try to unzip the file, however, I hit a snag where I can't seem to locate the recently downloaded file. If it helps, this is the block of code related to the downloading and unzipping process:

```
# Click on Map Link
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.linksubmit[value=\"▸ Map\"]").click()
# Download Data
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buttons"]/a[4]/img').click()

# Locate recently downloaded file
path = 'C:/.../Download'
list = os.listdir(path)
time_sorted_list = sorted(list, key=os.path.getmtime)
file_name = time_sorted_list[len(time_sorted_list)-1]
```

Specifically, this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-89-3f1d00dac284>", line 3, in <module>
    time_sorted_list = sorted(list, key=os.path.getmtime)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'grid-m1b566d31a87cba1379e113bb93fdb61d5be5b128.zip'
```

I tried troubleshooting the code by deleting it and placing another file in the directory, and I was able to find the random file, but not the recently downloaded file. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: First of all, don't use `list` for your variable names when you are working with `lists` already. That will likely cause namespace issues. Second, `os.listdir` does not list the full path. So you need to replace `list = os.listdir(path)` with `file_list = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]`.

Comment: Also, replace `[len(time_sorted_list)-1]` with just `[-1]`.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29159824/2988730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not use `list` for a variable name. That hides the `list` constructor from being readily available to use somewhere else in your program. Second, `os.listdir` does not return the full path of the files in that directory. If you want the full path, there are two things you can do:

You can use `os.path.join`:

```
import zipfile


path = 'C:/.../Download'
file_list = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
time_sorted_list = sorted(file_list, key=os.path.getmtime)
file_name = time_sorted_list[-1]
myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)
for contained_file in myzip.namelist():
    if all(n in contained_file.lower() for n in ('corn', 'irrigation', 'high', 'brazil')):
        with myzip.open(contained_file) as f:
            # save data to a CSV file
```

You can also use the `glob` function from the `glob` module:

```
from glob import glob
import zipfile


path = 'C:/.../Download'
file_list = glob(path+"/*")
time_sorted_list = sorted(file_list, key=os.path.getmtime)
file_name = time_sorted_list[-1]

myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)
for contained_file in myzip.namelist():
    if all(n in contained_file.lower() for n in ('corn', 'irrigation', 'high', 'brazil')):
        with myzip.open(contained_file) as f:
            # save data in a CSV file
```

Either should work.

Comment: How would I incorporate either of the two solutions to unzip a file?

Comment: @user2105555 see the edits. Also, are you looking to extract the contents of the zip file or do you wish to read the contents of a specific file from the whole zip file?

Comment: I wish to locate a specific file within the zip file, save it as a csv, and rename the file as a combination of the selections from the selenium procedure. For example, if I selected Corn for crops, Irrigation for water supply, High for input level, Brazil for country, then the file name should be Crops_Corn-WaterSupply_Irrigation-InputLevel_High-Country_Brazil, or something similar.

Comment: @user2105555 please see the edits. The added lines should look for a file whose name contains the keywords you mentioned. If there is a file with all those words in its name, then you open it and read its contents into a CSV file. This should work. If you have any other question, you may want to ask a new question since this question was about `os.listdir`.

Comment: If it helps, the downloaded zip file is randomly generated. One of the files within the zip file is called data.asc. I want to rename the data.asc file as a combination of the variables and parameters I selected previously.